# bad output Item"Name" of List "Whereabouts" SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

my programm takes data of version history elements of list sharepoint and put data in txt
 file. output "Name" ListItems and "Location". all ok, but unfortunately very bad output "Name". in my opinion problem in this line

```
string strFirstName = Convert.ToString(objVersion["Name"]);
```

bad output :

Name 4049;#Zabiyakin Makar ,#STALT\Zabiyakin,# Zabiyakin@stalt.ru,#,#Zabiyakin Makar Location В
Name 4049;#Zabiyakin Makar ,#STALT\Zabiyakin,# Zabiyakin@stalt.ru,#,#Zabiyakin Makar Location Home

i want output :

Name Zabiyakin Makar Location В
Name Zabiyakin Makar Location Home

code program :

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.IO;
namespace ControlTest.Layouts.ControlTest
{
    public partial class ApplicationPage1 : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string ListUrl = "/Deps/sup/Lists/Whereabouts";
            SPList objList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Whereabouts"];
            SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
            objQuery.Query = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value                 
            Type=\"Counter\">0 </Value></Gt></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection objItemColl = objList.GetItems(objQuery);  
            foreach (SPListItem objItem in objItemColl) 
            {
                SPListItemVersionCollection objVerisionColl = objItem.Versions;
                if (objVerisionColl.Count > 1)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItemVersion objVersion in objVerisionColl)  
                    {
                        int versionID = objVersion.VersionId; 
                        DateTime timeofcreation = objVersion.Created;  
                        string strVersionLabel = objVersion.VersionLabel;
                        SPListItem objLstItm = objVersion.ListItem;
                        string strFirstName = Convert.ToString(objVersion["Name"]);
                        //string strFirstName = 
                        ((SPFieldUserValue)objVersion["Name"]).User.Name;
                        string strPlace = Convert.ToString(objVersion["location"]);
                        System.IO.TextWriter writer = new 
                        StreamWriter(@"C:\custommenuoutput.txt", true);
                        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} location: {1}", 
                        strFirstName, strPlace));
                        writer.Close();

                    }

                }
              }
           }
     }
  }
```

how to make good output ?
please, help me !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SPUserFieldValue to get the friendly name.  See sample below.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spvm");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["DemoList"];
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById[1];
SPFieldUserValue objUserFieldValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["User"].ToString());
```

Once you get this object SPFieldUserValue ( objUserFieldValue) then you can retrieve each and every property of that user by following way.

```
objUserFieldValue.User.LoginName;
objUserFieldValue.User.Name;
objUserFieldValue.User.ID;
objUserFieldValue.User.Groups;
objUserFieldValue.User.Roles;
objUserFieldValue.User.Email;
objUserFieldValue.User.Sid;
objUserFieldValue.User.UserToken;
```